# CSS GRID not able to rearrange items with order:;

Tags: css, css-grid

I’m trying to rearrange the order of a CSS GRID.

But apparently all grid items have a default order value of 0. So `order: 1;` applied to a grid item would make after everything else, not before.

I want all my grid items to have by default an ascending order. So I can use `order: 2;` and have the item actually placing on the second place.

Can you help me please?!

Here’s an example, (my actual code is a bit more complicated)

```
<div class="grid">

<p class="item">1</p>
<p class="item">2</p>
<p class="item two">3</p>
<p class="item">4</p>

</div>
```

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.two { order: 2; }
```

I’ve tried doing this, but it’s not working;

```
.item:nth-child(1) { order:1; }
.item:nth-child(2) { order:2; }
.item:nth-child(3) { order:3; }
.item:nth-child(4) { order:4; }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3695vs27/

Comment: in your case you can use `grid-column:2` and it should work

Comment: With your edit, you've just got the natural order anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by not working. If I do your two code snippets then the 3 moves to the end of the list and is 1243. If I replace the .two line with your nth-child calls they are in order of 1,2,3,4. Everything is 0 to start with. When you only assign a value to .two then the other 3 are all 0,0,0 and occur in the natural order that the html has them. Even if you didn't get that before, the second one (with the nth-child settings) works as I would expect. What are you getting on that one that you don't expect and what do you want it to be instead?

Comment: @Rodger I need them to have the order set to 1234 etc. instead all of them having order: 0. 
So when I decide to move item 16 before item 5 I don’t have to define the order of all 16 of them but I just put a class to the item I want to move (16). Here we have 4 items but it could be 16, 31 or 100 it doesn’t matter.

Comment: Ok, so you will need to do what you have in the nth-child examples. This can be automated with javascript but if you are talking pure html/css then it is just some manual typing to do it. ... but you say that is also not working. What does that mean in regards to those?

Comment: @Rodger from what I’ve seen .two isn’t overwriting the nth-child so I’m not able to change the order because of that

Comment: Strange thing is if I do revers the order of nth-childs I’m able to move .two around like I want to (but the whole grid content is backwards)

Comment: `
.item:nth-child(1) { order:4; }
.item:nth-child(2) { order:3; }
.item:nth-child(3) { order:2; color: red }
.item:nth-child(4) { order:1; }

.item.two { order:1; color: green }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order, you'll see the default value for order is `0` so anything without order explicitly set will be the leading elements, then explicitly set sources apply.

You could use something like the following.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) { order:3; }
.item:nth-child(3) { order:2; }
.item:nth-child(4) { order:4; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">

<p class="item">1</p>
<p class="item">2</p>
<p class="item two">3</p>
<p class="item">4</p>

</div>
```

Or getting slightly tricky we can use the generic sibling combinator to deal with elements that occur after the swapped elements.

**Edit based on comment**

If we apply the class to the element we want to move *up* the order instead of the one we want to move down, we can doe this with 1 class and 3 selectors, making use of sibling selectors and a little bit of working with specificity.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

/*Swap the elements - now targeting the element we want to move UP*/
.item.three{ order:3; }
/*Move the next item sibling down*/
.item.three + .item { order:2; }
/*Deal with the elements after the swap with some sibling combinators 
by targeting all the siblings of the immediate sibling we targeted above*/
.item.three + .item ~ .item { order:4; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">

<p class="item">1</p>
<p class="item three">2</p>
<p class="item">3</p>
<p class="item">4</p>
<p class="item">5</p>
<p class="item">6</p>
<p class="item">7</p>

</div>
```

**Moving an item DOWN**

We can do it downwards too, it gets a little bit trickier though. Doing this for any given number will be hard as you need to know what element is going where. This is something that is probably beyond the reach of CSS at the moment and you may be better off with some javascript.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

/*Target the element to move down*/
.item.two{ order:2; }
/*Now we need to know where we are moving the item to and use nth-child again*/
.item:nth-child(2) { order:3; }
/*Adjust the remaining siblings, but not the one we've already moved*/
.item:nth-child(2) ~ .item:not(.two) { order:4; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">

<p class="item">1</p>
<p class="item">2</p>
<p class="item">3</p>
<p class="item">4</p>
<p class="item two">5</p>
<p class="item">6</p>
<p class="item">7</p>

</div>
```

**Going the Javascript route**

To enable arbitrary placement via class we'll use javascript to give each element a native order which our css will override.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".grid .item");

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  //Only update items without a modifying class
  if(items[i].classList.length == 1) {
    items[i].style.order=i;
  }
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.two {order:2; color:red;}
.six {order:6; color:green;}
.ten {order:10; color:blue;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

<p class="item">1</p>
<p class="item">2</p>
<p class="item six">3</p>
<p class="item">4</p>
<p class="item two">5</p>
<p class="item">6</p>
<p class="item">7</p>
<p class="item">8</p>
<p class="item">9</p>
<p class="item">10</p>
<p class="item">11</p>
<p class="item">12</p>
<p class="item">13</p>
<p class="item">14</p>
<p class="item ten">15</p>
<p class="item">16</p>

</div>
```

**BUT if i was going down the javascript path, i'd skip classes for ordering and use data attributes.**

Data attributes can be styles using the attribute selector. This way your list of elements can be arbitrarily long and you don't have to worry about a CSS class for each insertion point.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".grid .item");

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    //if we have a data attribute use that, otherwise use the natural order
    items[i].style.order= items[i].dataset.order ? items[i].dataset.order :  i;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}


[data-order] {
font-weight:bold;
background-color:#EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

<p class="item">1</p>
<p class="item">2</p>
<p class="item" data-order="6">3</p>
<p class="item">4</p>
<p class="item" data-order="2">5</p>
<p class="item">6</p>
<p class="item">7</p>
<p class="item">8</p>
<p class="item">9</p>
<p class="item">10</p>
<p class="item">11</p>
<p class="item">12</p>
<p class="item">13</p>
<p class="item">14</p>
<p class="item" data-order="10">15</p>
<p class="item">16</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! But what I’m actually trying to do (not even sure if it’s possible) I want to be able to add a class to a said item and have it placed on the right place. 

In your example you defined the order inside `nth-child` but I need to sort them thru classes ( .two ) in html

Comment: I'll see if I can make something work with my second example, I think you will need two classes though.

Comment: Done, with on class if you can target the element you want to move UP instead of the one to move down.

Comment: Thank you for your time Jon, I really appreciate! But what if I need to reorder 3 items out of 16?! Let’s say I want to move item 4 to 1, 15 to 6, 10 to 7? That’s why I was trying to have all items order set 1234 etc so when I add a class with the new order they actually go there. I don’t even how to explain it

Comment: In that case you have two options: 1) Every Element *must* have an order value with the native order. 2) Javascript

Comment: So nth-child for option 1) isn’t doable? I’ve to add order:; separately to every item?

Comment: @Woolflow you can use the grid-row/grid-column position : 
`.item.two {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}` https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BaNjZba If you have mediaqueries reordering col numbers, update the grid position too ;)

Comment: @Woolflow - to use the `order` property, yes, for every element *above* the first re-ordered element. Without the property being set it is `0` which  will display **before** any element with a set value. If this list is coming from a server-side technology, you a better off re-ordering there.

Comment: @G-Cyr while that will work in regards to the initial request, this has *evolved* to re-positioning any amount of items in an arbitrarily  long list of elements. Which, in my opinion, is not a job well suited to CSS alone.

Comment: @JonP that is his own soup . a grid template + a position number , the op should be able to find out which cell to select . i'm not making an answer of it , that was the first comment about. for the reordering via order, javascript could help and then not to have to mind about it anymore beside setting the right class here or there ;) that's where i would go if it's to be reused or to be often updated.

Comment: @Woolflow I suggest you look at G-Cyr codepen. The row/column option certainly is workable but still requires a css class for every possible insertion point. `order` is probably no the right tool for the job here, even CSS may not be the right tool. I suspect we have a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)